# Split string with delimiter in C - wrong count, does not split properly

Tags: c, string, delimiter

I want to split string (line) of words with a given delimiter. I wrote this code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned int countWords(char *stringLine)
{
    unsigned int count = 0;
    char* tmp = stringLine;
    char* last = 0;
    const char delim = '/';

    while (*tmp)
    {
        if (delim == *tmp)
        {
            count++;
            last = tmp;
        }
        tmp++;
    }
    return count-1;
}

char **getWordsFromString(char *stringLine)
{
    char** sizeNames = 0;
    unsigned int count = 0;
    const char *delim = "/";

    count = countWords(stringLine);

    sizeNames = malloc(sizeof(char*) * count);
    if(sizeNames == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    if (sizeNames)
    {
        size_t idx  = 0;
        char* token = strtok(stringLine, delim);
        while (token)
        {
            if(idx < count)
            {
                exit(-1);
            }
            *(sizeNames + idx++) = strdup(token);
            token = strtok(0, delim);
        }
        if(idx == count - 1)
        {
            exit(-1);
        }
        *(sizeNames + idx) = 0;
    }

    return sizeNames;
}

void showWords(char *stringLine)
{
    unsigned int size = countWords(stringLine), i = 0;
    char** sizeNames = getWordsFromString(stringLine);
    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", sizeNames[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char words[] = "hello/world/!/its/me";

    int c = countWords(words);
    printf("c = %d\n", c);
    showWords(words);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that my code does not work right. It shows a proper number of words in a string but does not split them, only gives me 255 return code. How can I improve it?

Comment: Given that you set `idx` to `0` three lines before, that `if ( idx < count ) { exit(-1); }` looks pretty fishy.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: changed it to `if(idx > count)` and it seems to work well :D

Comment: @mirx: don't use `exit(-1)`. The argument to `exit` should be an integer in the range `[0, 255]` ("only the least significant 8 bits (that is, status & 0377) shall be available to a waiting parent process", as posix says) which is why you're getting a return code of 255.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
size_t idx  = 0;
char* token = strtok(stringLine, delim);
while (token)
{
    if(idx < count)
    {
        exit(-1);
    }
```

given that you set `idx` to `0`, as long as `count` is greater than zero you'll always `exit()` here. Likely you want a different `if` condition. Exit codes are probably unsigned on your system, so that `-1` is just getting translated to `255`.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. Can I ask you slightly different question? Modified my code, but found some memory leaks. When trying to remove them, I got segfault. Heres my modified code which gives seg faults: http://pastie.org/private/v4m5bdg28be28fn9h5uta. When I comment frees, its ok but gives memory leaks.. Maybye you know how to solve it? Thank you

Comment: If you have another question, you should just ask a new question on Stack Overflow, comments are not a good place for this.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer using for-loop notation with strtok...  and I would write the core loop like this:

```
if (sizeNames)
{                                                                                                                       
    size_t idx  = 0;
    char *token;
    for( token = strtok(stringLine, delim);
         token && idx<count;
         token = strtok(NULL, delim), idx++)
    {
        *(sizeNames + idx) = strdup(token);
    }
    *(sizeNames + idx) = NULL;
}
```

But, since you are NULL-terminating after the last word, be sure to use count+1 in the following, or else the above line `*(sizeNames + idx) = NULL;` could segfault:

```
sizeNames = malloc(sizeof(char*) * (count+1));
```

PS... your countWords routine returns the wrong answer, too.  Probably want to replace:

```
return count-1;
```

With:

```
if( (last+1)==tmp )
   return count;                                                                                                        

return count+1;
```

Also, the memory you allocate with `strdup()` is never freed anywhere, so you will get leak errors if you run this through valgrind.

Note, you don't really have to use `strdup()` since `strtok()` leaves NULs in the places where it found delimiters in the source string, so you could have written:

```
*(sizeNames + idx) = token;
```

in the heart of the for-loop.  Because of this destructive behavior, `strtok()` is sometimes only run on a copy of a buffer to be analyzed.

Comment: about freeing memory - can you please look at my new question - related with this code? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23277830/split-string-with-delimiter-in-c-segmentation-faults-invalid-free